# Dynamic Data in an RDLC Report Footer across Multiple Pages

Tags: rdlc

I created an RDLC report (based on a stored procedure) that contains lists. I need to display data from one of those lists in the report footer across every page. However this data only shows in a list on the first page, so that is the only page on which it shows in the footer also. I’ve researched this but haven’t found much information. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Something you can try, don't know for sure if it will work.  Create a formula that returns the data you want to display, then put the formula field on a text area in the footer.

Comment: Thanks ScottTx, I have a formula/expression there already (=ReportItems!list.Value). The value is only displaying in the footer of the page where that list value is displayed (versus repeating in each page footer).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing a textbox in the second page area, setting the text color to white and sending it to the back. If I hid the textbox (or table - I tried that too), the footer object could not reference it. So, setting the text color to white and placing it behind another object worked. It seems like this is a kludgy way to do a simple report operation but is apparently necessary.